# Reg Expression - loop through array and find first letter in lists in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm looping through an array, where I'm checking if the keydown (the key the user presses) matches a word in the array - if it does, it alerts the matched lists.. Like this:

```
        $.each(keywords, function(i) {
            var rSearchTerm = new RegExp('\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b','i');
            if (keywords[i].match(rSearchTerm)) {
              keywordIndex = i;
              alert(keywords[i]);
            }
        });
```

This works fine, but it checks for an entire word.. How do I make the regular expression check for the first letter in each lists instead?

Comment: Does the `keywords` array hold words or entire strings? I.e., can we just check the first letter of each array element or the first letter for all words within the array element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `searchTerm` is a single letter and `keywords` is an **array of strings of words**:

```
$.each(keywords, function(i) {
    var rSearchTerm = new RegExp('\\b' + searchTerm + '\\w*\\b','i');
    if (keywords[i].match(rSearchTerm)) {
        keywordIndex = i;
        alert(keywords[i]);
    }
});
```

The `\w` is a [character class shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand). The regex matches a word boundary, followed by the `searchTerm` letter, followed by none (single letter) or more (start of word) word characters. The last word boundary (`\b`) can be omitted.

---

If `searchTerm` is a single letter and `keywords` is an **array of words**:

```
$.each(keywords, function(i) {
    if (keywords[i].substring(0, 1) == searchTerm) {
        keywordIndex = i;
        alert(keywords[i]);
    }
});
```

---

**BTW:** You can (and should?) add a `return false;` statement after the `alert();` in order to break the loop (if you only need to find the first occurance).

Comment: That was very fast and the first method works best for me :) Though I have an extra question.. I only want it to return one result (so i've included return false in my loop). But it seems as if it skips whitespaces with your first method. Fx, if I have this in my array: "tralala d" and "d", it finds the "tralala d" instead of the "d" - is it possible to make it only find the list that starts with the keydown letter?

Comment: @Don Pedro That would be the second solution, right? Or am I mistaken? You may want to post an example of `keywords` and what to return for different `searchTerm` letters.

Comment: Hehe nope, sorry.. The second method would choose both in my example above ("tralala d" and "d"), where it only has to choose "d" :)

Comment: @Don Pedro See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/Bx96g/) JSfiddle. It's the second solution. I'm sure we're not really talking about the same :)

Comment: Oh ye, I see.. The second method is the one I have to use ;) It's just because I use ":contains(keywords[i])" to highlight the results, and it of course highlights all of them.. doh!

Comment: @Don Pedro Oh, time do create a `:startswith()` content filter then :) `jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {startswith: function(e, i, m) { return m[3] && $(e).text().charAt(0) == m[3]; }});` (untested!)